# ionic 3 calling page class call custom method from custom common class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

we have several vendors, their HTML pages only different but backend logic will be same.

I have separate common controller class for calling web service part.

my common class code

```
    export class LoginController {  

    static callLoginService(value : any) {
        //TO-DO calling web service
        if (value.username == "admin" && value.password == "admin" ) {
            console.log("===Yes====");
            return true
        }else{
            console.log("===NO====");
            return false
        }
    }

    static f1(){
        console.log("funtion1");
    }

}
```

in `Login.ts` class.

```
  submitForm(value: any):void{
    console.log('Form submitted!')
    console.log(value.username);
    console.log(value.password);


    LoginController.f1();
    LoginController.callLoginService(value);
    console.log(this.loginController.callLoginService(value));
  }
```

After submitting form, error saying

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__controllers_login_loginController__.a.callLoginService is not a function
```

please help me or any guides

Comment: any particular reason you are using static functions instead of provider?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern which you have used is not a recommended pattern at all with the Ionic/Angular.You need to use `providers` when you're dealing with the 3rd party services or like that.

> Providers allow you to create a self-contained service that provides
>   some kind of functionality to your application. The role of a provider
>   might include things like fetching data from a server, performing
>   operations on data, sharing data, providing a set of complicated
>   mathematical operations, and so on.

[**Link**](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-why-and-when-to-use-providers-in-ionic-2/)

You can use below `CLI` to create a `provider`

```
ionic generate provider MyTestProvider
```

You can read more about [**provider here**](https://www.djamware.com/post/58e657b680aca764ec903c2d/ionic-3-and-angular-4-mobile-app-example).